Freeradius TLS Certificate chain - 1 intermediate CA cert(s) untrusted
I'm setting up freeradius 3.2.6 on Ubuntu 24.04. I create the certificates with the script that comes and I manage to connect via TLS. The problem is that this warning appears:
To forbid these certificates see 'reject_unknown_intermediate_ca'
I verified the client certificates with openssl and it says OK. I don't use intermediate AC.
The /mods-enable/eap file is configured so that ca.pem is in the correct directory.
I tried everything but I can't find a way to solve that. If anyone can give me a hand, I appreciate it.
